# Как отделить нужный символ в string от всего остального?

Tags: c#, .net

Я пишу программу в которой мне нужно отделять символы такие как: +,-,*,/ от всех остальных символов в input-е типа string.

Как мне это правильно сделать, потому что у меня не получается. За ответ буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это простое решение, это то что вам нужно?

```
using System;

class HelloWorld {
  static void Main() {
    string testString = Console.ReadLine();
    string charsDetect = "+-*/";
    
    string newString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < testString.Length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < charsDetect.Length; j++) {
            if (testString[i] == charsDetect[j]) {
                newString += testString[i];
            }
        } 
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine(newString);
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
  }
}
```

Comment: Да это то что нужно. Огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string removableChars = Regex.Escape(@"@&'()<>#");
string pattern = "[" + removableChars + "]";

string testString = "sdfsdf<df>#kdfdsf(";

var specialChars = Regex.Matches(testString , pattern )
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
    .ToArray();
string withoutSpecialChars= Regex.Replace(testString , pattern, "");
        
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("  ", specialChars));
        Console.WriteLine(withoutSpecialChars);
    }
}
```